# Unable to run tests inside the TV app apk

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I build the TV apk from the following Google source.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TV/+/master

TV apk have lot of tests inside the app. (common, func, Input, Jank & Unit)
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TV/+/master/tests/

I am trying to run these TV tests, But no instrumentation tests found when i run the following commend.

```
adb shell pm list instrumentation
```

**How to run TV app tests?** do i need to build the tests separately?

Answer (score 1):

You have to import them as separate modules in your TV app project. 

To import a module in Android Studio:

<kbd>File</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>New</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>Import module</kbd>

In the opened window select the path to some module (for example **/tests/input/** directory)

> *.gitignore 
>  Android.mk 
>  AndroidManifest.xml 
>  LiveChannelsAndroidStyle.xml 
>  assets/ 
>  common/
>   open_source_project.LICENSE 
>  open_source_project.README 
>
>   proguard.flags 
>  res/ 
>  src/ 
>
>   **tests**
>  usbtuner/ 
>  version.mk*

To be able to build this project you will also have to import other directories as moudules (common, usbtuner).